# Special sum of squares of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Could anyone please help me evaluate the following sum of squares of binomial coefficients:
$$
\sum_{\ell=k}^n \begin{pmatrix} \ell \\ k \end{pmatrix}^2, \quad \mbox{where} \quad 0\leq k \leq n,
$$
or, at least, get an upper bound for it? 
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: $k$ is some constant?

Comment: Any more context on the upper bound you need? For instance, is this the runtime of some algorithm?

Comment: Just an idea. Perhaps someone can make use of it. $\binom{L}{K}^2$ is the coefficient of $(xy)^K$ in $(1+x)^L(1+y)^L$.

Comment: Surely: I am trying to determine if the series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^{2k} \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{m+1} 2^m}{(2m)!} r^{2m} \sum_{\ell=m}^{k-m} \ell^2 \ldots (\ell-m+1)^2 r^{2\ell}, \quad |t| <1, \quad |r| < 1, $$ converges or not and thought that the above sum might help me with that...